# Multi-level marketing scheme claims to be a partner of my employer

Tags: customer-relation

A multi-level marketing company / pyramid scheme claims to be "a partner" of various well-known car manufacturers on their website, including my employer.

Employees of the MLM company are given access to attractive lease conditions for cars from those manufacturers, which usually also bear decals of the MLM company.

I don't believe my employer is aware that the MLM company uses the employers reputation to appear more legitimate.

To whom (at my company) could I report such (potentially fraudulent) advertisement / claims to?

Comment: Your employer? Have you spoken to anyone at your work about it?

Comment: @Draken Not yet. I'm unsure which department would be responsible.

Comment: I did not understand how is your company evolved, can you clarify more? Is your company one of those car manufacturers?

Comment: That's company specific, you'd probably need to ask people at your company. Try the Legal department first and they should be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: @renanAlmeida828 Yes, I clarified the question above.

Answer (score 7):

In your situation, I would take the website, news and other media you have regarding this - supposedly - miss usage of your company's name to one of this departments:

1. Legal Department (Thank you [@Draken](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/52713/draken))
2. Marketing Department (Brand management)

Present them the content saying: 
*Hey! I found this online and it felt strange to me, almost like it should not be there. Can you check it?*

If they get surprised, you know you did a good thing. I would then expect them to fix this regarding company's internal processes.

Comment: 1. Corporate Communications / Public Relations Department
2. Legal Department
3. Brand Management

Answer (score 0):

You can start the discussion with the legal department. If you're not particularly aware of the people / contact to get in  touch with, the second best option always is to reach out to your manager - they'll find out the proper channel for you.

Comment: @Cloud This is not going to do any good. Just FYI. Serial downvotes are against the community rule and general ethics.